# Undefined Params React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following code to check if the user is not logged in:

```
if (navigate.params.user) {
          drawer = <Button transparent onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}><Icon name="person" /></Button>;
      } else {
          drawer = <Button transparent onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}><Icon name="person" /></Button>;
      }
```

If the user is not logged in or hasn't accessed the login screen the param is, of course, going to be undefined. However, this returns an error saying that undefined is not an object.

Comment: It might help try navigate.params.state.user

Comment: @KumarA Also undefined. I need to find a way to make the if work with undefined. And ==undefined returns the same error

Comment: `navigate.params && navigate.params.user`

Comment: @JaromandaX That gives Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `onPress` of type `boolean` supplied to `TouchableNativeFeedback`, expected `function`. and  also Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: weird, how can changing the condition in the if statement do that

Comment: @JaromandaX You are good. I was missing the () =>  on my onPress. Thanks!